# EC2 - Connect to running instance by using the API

Tags: amazon-ec2

I create an EC2 instance via the provided interface, and I am using the AWS API to connect to the existing running instance, but when I run the following code I get "You have 0 Amazon EC2 instance(s) running.":

```
DescribeAvailabilityZonesResult availabilityZonesResult = ec2.describeAvailabilityZones();
System.out.println("You have access to " + availabilityZonesResult.getAvailabilityZones().size() +
                " Availability Zones.");

DescribeInstancesResult describeInstancesRequest = ec2.describeInstances();
List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();
Set<Instance> instances = new HashSet<Instance>();

for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
    instances.addAll(reservation.getInstances());
}

System.out.println("You have " + instances.size() + " Amazon EC2 instance(s) running.");
```

Do you have any ideas about what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you double checked that your instances are actually up and running, they most likely are not in the "us-east-1" instance region (which is the default one that the AWS SDK assumes).

So set your `AmazonEC2Client` instance to point to the correct endpoint and everything should be fine, e.g. for Europe (Ireland):

```
ec2.setEndpoint("ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

More details, as well as links to where you can find the endpoint strings, in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970252/1947205).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it worked. Is there a way to automatically get this information?

Comment: I am at least not aware of any such method.