# Connect and loop through 100 EC2 instances and find the memory usage and the programs running in them

Tags: java, php, memory, amazon-ec2, resource-utilization

I want to figure out the memory usage of 100 EC2 instances and the name of the scripts that are running in them (Probably push it to a DB).

Any ideas on how to do this the most efficient way in PHP or Java.

Comment: Yes.  Don't use either and use parallel ssh instead with a shell script.

Comment: Use this to programmatically connect to EC2 instances : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006555/ec2-connect-to-running-instance-by-using-the-api?rq=1

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHoelzer, trying to figure out something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going out to 100 instances and doing stuff (which is hard to scale), you should **have the instances automatically report this information to a central service**.

For example, here is a Linux script that can **measure memory** and send the metrics back to Amazon CloudWatch: [Monitoring Memory and Disk Metrics for Amazon EC2 Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html)

You could use a similar script to send your own metric to CloudWatch, particularly if it is a numeric answer.

However, if you do decide to centrally query each server for information, you should use the [Systems Manager Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) that can **automatically execute scripts** on multiple Amazon EC2 instances simultaneously.

Comment: I do not want to play around with the instances as it is in production. This is a one time activity and thus looking for a quick script. But this is interesting, i'll look into it.